# Tuleap version number

Tags: tuleap

I'm not the administrator of our Tuleap installation and I'd like to perform some customization that is version dependent. I can't seem to find the version of my current installation. Can anyone tell me where can I find the version number for the instance of Tuleap that I'm using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I finally found it. By clicking on the tuleap icon in the left hand corner, an about page is displayed. At the very very bottom of that page in very small print is the version.[image]